# Laravel 5.1 - Password Reset returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to make a password reset function. 
Using this guide  (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords) I was able to set up the views and the emails.

So right now, I have to enter my email, then it emails me to a link with a token (like this http://project.dev/password/reset/d500d7fb15f0dd12e079bb38c23baeba51a8849829d07aeff244ec80711ad015) and I get to the view where I have to enter my email and my new password.

Here is the code for my view

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'New Password')

@section('content')
    <div class="registrationform">
        <div class="row "><div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"><div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <h4>New Password</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12">

                                <form id="loginform" action="" method="POST" role="form" style="display: block;">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="john@snow.com" value="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" tabindex="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="confirm">
                                            </div></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12">

                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when I fill in the form it gives an error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

here is the complete error I receive

```
in RouteCollection.php line 219
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 746
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I've been looking for a solution for some time now, but I haven't found anything yet, I hope one fo you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the error telling you?

`MethodNotAllowedException` means the method (GET, POST, etc) you're using to retrieve that URL is not allowed.

If you're getting this when you load the page then GET is not allowed. If you're getting this when you submit the form then POST is not allowed.

Check your `app/Http/routes.php` file and make sure you have both GET and POST for the `password/reset/{token}` route.